# takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given) when including self

Tags: python, self

Everytime I call my function `def hello(self,value)` I get an error : `takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)` so what could I do ?

Or is there another possibility to do this: `self.statusitem.setImage_(self.iconsuccess)`?

EDIT:

simple representation of my code

```
Class A:
   func_in_class_B(value)

Class B:
def finishLaunching(self):
   self.statusitem.setImage_(self.icon)
def func_in_class_B(self,value)
   self.statusitem.setImage_(self.iconsuccess)
```

Class A is a background thread and Class B my main thread, and I want to manipulate `self.statusitem.setImage_(self.icon)

Comment: how do you call `hello`?

Comment: I think you're going to need to show us a little more code than that.  How does `hello` line up with `self.statusitem.setImage_(...)`?  how do those thoughts connect?  Is `hello` defined as a method on a class, or is it a regular function?

Comment: Added a simple representation of my code

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you aren't calling your hello function correctly. Given the following class definition:

```
class Widget(object):
    def hello(self, value):
        print("hello: " + str(value))
```

You are probably calling it like a static function like this:

```
Widget.hello(10)
```

Which means no instance of a widget class gets passed as a first param. You need to either set up the hello function to be static:

```
class Widget(object):
    @staticmethod
    def hello(value):
        print("hello: " + str(value))

Widget.hello(10)
```

or call it on a specific object like this:

```
widget = Widget()
widget.hello(10)
```

Comment: Removing the `self` reference as the first param won't make the function static, self is just a name for the first parameter. Use the `staticmethod` decorator instead

Comment: @Kos ahh, i've never had to set up a static function in python. feel free to edit the answer to make it accurate.

Answer (score 1):

This is most probably because your hello function is not a class member. In that case you need not provide self in the method declaration....i.e. instead of hello(self,value) just say hello(value)

For example...this snippet works absolutely fine

```
def hello(value):
    print 'Say Hello to ' + value

hello('him')
```

If this is not the case then please provide your code snippet to help you further.