# Exception while calling ODOO API

Tags: java, android, json, odoo, rpc

I have this method in my Python file

```
@api.model
    def get_wallet_balance(self, ID_number):
        wallet_balance = 0.0
        partner = self.env['res.partner'].sudo().search(
            [('member_id_number', '=', ID_number)],limit=1
        )
        if partner:
            wallet_balance = partner.wallet_balance
        print 'wallet_balance========================',wallet_balance
        return wallet_balance
```

Calling method

```
    App context = (App) getApplicationContext();
    OArguments oArguments = new OArguments();
    oArguments.add(user.getUserId());
    final OdooClient client = new OdooClient.Builder(context)
            .setHost(OConstants.URL_ODOO)
            .setSession(user.getSessionId()).build();

    client.call_kw("res.partner", "get_wallet_balance", arguments, response);
```

Error

I am getting the following error

```
E/a: ERROR: 
     **** get_wallet_balance() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given) ****
     on http://*****/web/dataset/call_kw/res.partner/get_wallet_balance [5946]
I/Choreographer: Skipped 124 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

I am able to call other methods which don't have arguments.
Can anyone please mention where I am going wrong?

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14693619/1271435